# E-mail validation, e-mail cannot be repeated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

How can I validate e-mails that they cannot be repeated? Okay I can push them from server to the array. What's next? How can I compare them? At this moment I have only validation by regex.

Comment: What do you mean by repeated?

Answer (score -1):

Server should check if email unique or not, and send response. Client just check if it's an email and not just a text